# Getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, attributeerror

I am getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

However, none of the posts on SO seem to be pertinent to my error. My issue is that I have no idea where my piece of code turns what seems to be an array into a string when appending.

Code:

```
import os
import hashlib
yn = True
var = []

while yn == True:
    print """
    1. Import from file
    2. Add new cards
    3. Look at the cards
    4. Delete cards  
    5. Modify cards  
    """
    ui = int(raw_input("Which option would you like to choose: "))
    if ui == 1:
        print "The directory is", os.getcwd()
        getcwdui = raw_input("Would you like to change the directory y/n: ")
        if getcwdui == "y":
            os.chdir(raw_input("Where would you like to change it to? Please make sure to include all necessary punctuation: "))
        else:
            print "\n"
        fileui = raw_input("Which file would you like to import?")
        file1 = open(fileui, "r")
        var = file1.read()
        var.split("]")
        file1.close()

#   [id, name, hp, set, setnum, rarity]
if ui == 2:
    name = raw_input("What is the name of the pokemon: ")
    hp = int(raw_input("What is the hp of the pokemon: "))
    setp = raw_input("What is the set of the pokemon: ")
    setnum = int(raw_input("What is the set number of the pokemon: "))
    rarity = raw_input("What is the rarity of the pokemon: ")
    copies = int(raw_input("How many copies of the card do you have: "))
    m = hashlib.md5()
    hashid = m.update(str(setnum))
    var.append([hashid, name, hp, setp, setnum, rarity])
    file1 = open(raw_input("What file would you like to open: "), "w")
    file1.write(str(var))
    file1.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
var.split("]")
```

Like all string methods, `str.split` does not work in-place because strings are immutable in Python.  Instead, it returns a *new* object, which is a list in this case.

If you want the value of `var` to change, you need to manually reassign the name:

```
var = var.split("]")
```

Otherwise, `var` will still be a string when you get to this line:

```
var.append([hashid, name, hp, setp, setnum, rarity])
```

Since strings do not have an `append` method, an `AttributeError` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the above answer works. You can fix the second part with `+=`:

```
var += [hashid, name, hp, setp, setnum, rarity]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: this would basically do the same thing as `.extend` which is not the same as `.append`...